# C Exception handling

Tags: c, windows, exception, internals

I would like to know how to handle exceptions in C, specifically `EXCEPTION_GUARD_PAGE` exceptions.

I will try explaining the situation more briefly:

I would like to mark a section/pages section as `PAGE_GUARD`, and whenever the program hits them I would like to perform a few tasks, I tried causing the exception with a classical `VirtualAlloc -> Write -> Exception` hit but I do know to catch the exception in C

I'd appreciate the help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MSDN has everything you need:

- [Using an Exception Handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681409%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [The try-except Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zazxh1a9%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

In this particular case you want something in this vein:

```c
__try
{
  /* Code that may cause exceptions... */
}
__except(GetExceptionCode() == EXCEPTION_GUARD_PAGE 
      ? EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER
      : EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH)
{
  /* Exception handling code... */
}
```

EDIT (in response to OP's comment):

The above code would do ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sw7cha4.aspx) is helpful again), but in this case there's more portable (no dependency on MSVC's extensions) and arguably less ugly solution: register a top-level exception filter using [SetUnhandledExceptionFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680634%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and let it handle the situation:

```c
/* Our top-level exception filter. */
LONG WINAPI MyUnhandledExceptionFilter(EXCEPTION_POINTERS* exceptionInfo)
{
  DWORD exceptionCode = exceptionInfo->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionCode;
  if(exceptionCode == EXCEPTION_GUARD_PAGE)
  {
    /* Handle the situation somehow... */
    /* ...and resume the exception from the place the exception was thrown. */
    return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION;
  }
  else
  {
    /* Unknown exception, let another exception filter worry about it. */
    return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH;
  }
}

/* Somewhere else in the code: */
SetUnhandledExceptionFilter(&MyUnhandledExceptionFilter);
```

Comment: Man that's ***ugly***!  I suppose not as ugly as blundering on after an error though.

Comment: You do not seem to understand my situation well
I allocate pages to a different section using VirtualAlloc, those pages are executable and will execute sometime - unknown
I want to mark those page as PAGE_GUARD and whenever they're accessed an exception will be raised - and the control will be transferred my exception handler

I tried using SetUnhandledExceptionFilter() but I may have done it wrong, I'd appreciate if someone could hint me a bit

Comment: @Software Monkey: I fully agree, but there's nothing I can do about that :( @tfs: okay, I've expanded the answer.

Comment: hey,
I've managed to get to the same code as you did, however the program does not seem to return from the exception - but exit 
How is it possible to continue execution after the exception code has finished ?

Comment: The above works for me. Are you sure you're returning EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION? What Windows version do you use?

Comment: The second example doesn't work, as resuming execution from where the exception was thrown will just rethrow it.